# Show error_log output in GAE on localhost like it does in production

Tags: php, google-app-engine

When I publish my Google App Engine app to run in production, if I've made an error in my PHP and I get an `error_log()` about an undefined variable or something, that code gets spewed directly to the browser and it breaks my HTML, breaks my JavaScript, etc.

However, when I run the app on `localhost`, the warning `error_log()`s are showing in the browser, and they aren't showing my GAE logs either! If I explicitly code an `error_log()`, that will show up in the GAE logs, but the PHP warnings aren't showing up.

So, I think my code is working fine, but when I publish then everything breaks and I'm in hot water.

How can I make my local GAE spew those warnings to the browser so I can get the same behavior that I'm seeing in production?

Comment: Try starting `dev_appserver.py` with the `--log_level=debug` option.

Comment: I would make sure your application at any point is not calling `ini_set('display_erors')` or `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Also check if errors are turned on in a `php.ini` in the root of your project. By default, those warnings should **not** be showing up in production.